# Seaborn Lmplot one line per category (hue) and a overall line

Tags: seaborn

While using lmplot I can make a different line for each category, like this:

```
sns.lmplot( x='x', y='y', data=df, hue='z')
```

Is there a way to aggregate all of this? What I mean is, if I have three categories for z (1,2,3), I want to have a line for 1, a line for 2, a line for 3, and an overall trendline for the whole dataset.

The df would be something like:

```
| x | y  | z |
|---|----|---|
| 1 | 2  | a |
| 2 | 6  | b |
| 3 | 6  | a |
| 4 | 12 | b |
| 5 | 10 | a |
| 6 | 18 | b |
```

Is this possible?

z=a has is times 2, z=b is times 3.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your `df` so that we can use it as a base for a discussion here?

Comment: Updated the post with a df

Answer (score 0):

One possiibility is to come back to the axes and replot data with `regplot`
Please refer to https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html#seaborn.regplot

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="white")
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'y': [2,6,6,12,10,18],
                   'z': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b','a', 'b']})
g = sns.lmplot(x='x', 
               y='y', 
               data=df, 
               hue='z',
               legend=False) # delegate legend to plt.legend further down
sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=df, 
            ax=g.axes.flat[0], 
            color="g",
            label='a+b',
            scatter=False,
            ci=68
            )
plt.legend()
g.savefig('/Users/massimopinto/Desktop/regplot.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

generates

[image: overlay with .map over the facetgrid axes]